# Preserve window.history.back() to use later

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history

I'm working on a checkout and i've a back button which triggers `window.history.back()` on click.

Works fine till the user make some change in cart, then the page reload and `window.history.back()` do the same than `window.reload()` because it gets the last page.

I know the best workaround with this could be apply Ajax to this cart updates by user input to keep `window.history.back()` inmutable to prev page before entering cart. But this is not possible on this project, it's a temporary prestashop and it will be fine to preserve `window.history.back()` when click on some modification button before submit to mantain the functionallity on back button.

I think this is not possible due to privacity but i want to know if someone had this problem before and which workaround will be better.

Using `history.go(-2)` will send to user two steps back so it's not ok for some use cases.

Maybe a global counter set to `-1` and then `--counter;` when entering or reloading cart will do the trick with `history.go(counter);`

Any suggestion to deal with this situation?
Thanks.

Comment: That mean you want to prevent browser to go back?

Comment: maybe you can save the last page url in a cookie and then load that url in the button as href

Comment: How do you get to the checkout page?  While not ideal, there are plenty of large sites that include a `&SourceUrl=` when going to a central page (eg checkout / error page / login page).  This gives your button a concrete return url  without needing to worry about history.   It does mean changing your checkout button wherever it appears.

Comment: Cookies are a bad idea as you'll need to destroy it, and when do you destroy this cookie or value? User could never press back button and the value will be preserved on this cookie with a sort of problems it may cause.

Comment: yup, setting an uri value could help but prestashop can change it when user interacts and i can't figure out how to ensure it, by the other way, there's a prettylink that kills usability and a link share could be pretty uggly. I'm dealing with a global var but donno why it is destroyed on page reload.

Comment: @JoelBonetRodríguez Don't solve the problem in the question. Add it as an answer yourself.

Comment: "I'm dealing with a global var but donno why it is destroyed on page reload. " Well, the variable gets reset everthing the page loads - because all of the code runs.

I think you want a local storage solution, save the URL in the local storage and only replace and use it by some conditions. 

I.e. user goes to checkout page, the back button is the previous page (recorded in local storage) the user refreshes the page the local storage checks if it will overwrite the url with the current one and not do it.

Comment: yup i tried a supposed js trick that didnt worked but i found a solution, check the post. Thanks anyway. PD: Storing local values are persistent, more than i need.

Comment: Please don't post your answer as part of the question, or put "SOLVED" in the title; it just makes things more confusing for future users if some of the answers are mixed into the question itself.  Post it as an answer instead.

Comment: @daniel-beck done, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved** using the following workaround:

Code:

```
/* inside the page where we want to preserve the "back" URI */
  <script>
var counter = 0;
      if(window.name != ""){
/* if window.name is set, assign the value to var counter*/
          counter = window.name;
      } else {
/* if it's not, init to 0. */
          counter = 0;
      }
/* Set window.name to counter value minus 1. It will be set to -1 the first time you enter the cartPage (on this example case) and it will be changed to -2, -3 etc each time you reload. */
      window.name = counter-1;
  </script>
/* On global.js */

if(window.location.href.indexOf("cartPage") === -1) {
    /* Reset window.name value if we're not on cartPage, to avoid errors */
    window.name = "";
}

/* The button: */

<a onclick="history.go(window.name)"> go back </a>
```

Hope it helps someone. 
Cheers!

Comment: I built this very workaround. However, I lose forward functionality. The forward button stays grey, as if the user didn't click back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
window.location.replace(document.referrer);
```

Comment: The result will be the same as history.back(). If the page reloads, the referrer of this document is the same page.

Comment: How about using a check in CartController that if the referrer is not from the cart itself, but from a different proper place of the website - write a value into cookie or session and then pass that as a variable into your template? If there's no value, redirect to homepage

Comment: Not a valid answer. Definetely. Because redirecting to homepage is just what i don't want. It will make the user search for the product again and could be frustrating. Write a cookie will preserve the value too long and waste more resources writting a cookie than assigning a single-window-global js variable. Session will need an ajax to save value and its persistence is not on my hand (or must not be).